# load div from php with javascript

Tags: php, jquery

I want to build an editable lists in php, javascript. My issue is that I want when a click on an item occurs, to load more details for this item in a div. Without extra details my code works fine. But I can't get the extras.. My code is : 
product.class

```
public function __toString(){

        // The string we return is outputted by the echo statement

        return '
        <li id="product-'.$this->data['productId'].'" class="product">

            <div class="text">'.$this->data['productName'].'</div>
            <div id="productDetails"></div>
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" class="edit" id="editProduct">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </div>                  
        </li>';
    }
```

product.js

```
    // Listening for a click on a edit button

$('.product a.edit').live('click',function(){

    var container = currentProduct.find('.text');

    if(!currentProduct.data('origText'))
    {
        // Saving the current value of the Category so we can
        // restore it later if the user discards the changes:

        currentProduct.data('origText',container.text());
    }
    else
    {
        // This will block the edit button if the edit box is already open:
        return false;
    }

    $('<input type="text">').val(container.text()).appendTo(container.empty());
    /*This is my main problem*/
    container.append($("#productDetails").load("productDetails.php", {id: currentProduct}));


     /*  
    // Appending the save and cancel links:  (This works fine)
    container.append(
        '<div class="editCategory">'+
            '<a class="saveChanges" href="#">Save</a> or <a class="discardChanges" href="#">Cancel</a>'+
        '</div>'
    );*/

});
```

How can I get "currentProduct" in my productDetails.php? I tried $_POST['id'], but I get nothing.

Comment: It is always wise to 1) check if the php file generates the correct output when requesting it from the browser directly (without ajax) 2) execute `print_r($_POST);` in your php file and post the results here and 3) define 'nothing' (as there is something like void or null, but nothing doesn't exist in computer science)

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.live()` has been removed from jQuery, it may be causing you an error.

Comment: live() works in other files..I have the correct version. @giorgio in case 1) it works fine..I get correct results, in case 2) I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$("#productDetails").load("productDetails.php", {id: currentProduct}, function(response, status, xhr){
    container.append(response);
});
```

---

What seems to me as `.load()` is a ajax call which is asynchronous by default, so `container` tries to `append` some data from php but at that point of time request is not completed and nothing is appended.

#### Solution:

As i see you can do it with callback function of `.load()` method, as suggested in the above code.

---

#### Side note:

You are using a method to bind `click` event in your case is `live` and this has been removed in the latest jQuery libraries from `1.9+` onwards, so make sure your version is less than `1.9` or better to upgrade the library and use the recommended method for it `.on()` to delegate the event, event delegation syntax is little different with `.on()`:

```
$(staticParent).on(event, selector, callback);
```

where `staticParent` is the closest static parent which was availble at the time of dom ready.

Comment: I tried the code you suggested but still get nothing. I 'll try the .on(), and I 'll tell you